# Get phone number to sit at bottom of thumbnail

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get the phone number to sit at the bottom of the thumbnail below the images. This is too allow for all three to line up. I have tried position fixed and bottom but neither have worked.

```
<div class="row text-center hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="position:fixed; top:50%; left:5%; right:5%;">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail" style="height:150px">
                    <img style="widht: 150px; height:100px" src="assets/logos/virgin-media.jpg">
                    <p><span style="color:#428BCA; font-size: 32px; bottom:50px">0871 703 7323</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail" style="height:150px">                
                    <img style="width:150px; height100px" src="assets/logos/talktalk.jpg">  
                    <p><span style="color:#428BCA; font-size: 32px; bottom:50px">08082 230 624</span></p>              
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail" style="height:150px">                
                    <img style="width:150px; height100px" src="assets/logos/bt.png">
                    <p><span style="color:#428BCA; font-size: 32px; bottom:50px">0871 703 7196</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have also made a bootply

http://www.bootply.com/PXayrqx4xx

Comment: Not sure I can see what your problem is... all the phone numbers are at the bottom beneath the thumbnails, right? http://www.bootply.com/c1rHkPPjSq

Comment: My images are different sizes and I need the numbers to line up

Comment: If you'd have been more careful, you'd have spotted the spelling and syntax errors. Widht in the first image should be width. Height100px in the second and third images should be Height: 100px. The corrections can be spotted here: http://www.bootply.com/B2x9qFCIdV With these corrections all three images are the same size; so what is the remaining problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's a fixed-up version with some extra rules:

```
#thumbs .thumbnail{
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}
#thumbs .thumbnail p{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

[Bootply here](http://www.bootply.com/adPXnDMJQQ)